# Display only captured groups

Tags: c#, regex, winforms

I'm trying to display **only** the captured regex groups (the ones surrounded by ()) but regardless what I've tried it displays both the captured ones and the matched ones.

What I am looking for is a solution that only displays the captured groups.

This is an example code that shows both groups as mentioned above:

```
RegexOptions ignoreSpace = checkEditIgnoreSpaces.Checked ? RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace : RegexOptions.None;
RegexOptions ignorecase = checkEditIgnoreCase.Checked ? RegexOptions.IgnoreCase : RegexOptions.None;
RegexOptions multiline = checkEditMultiline.Checked ? RegexOptions.Multiline : RegexOptions.Singleline;
RegexOptions ignoreUnnamedGroups = checkEditCaptureUnnamedGroups.Checked ? RegexOptions.None : RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture;

MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(myRichTextBox1.Text, pattern, ignorecase | ignoreSpace | multiline | ignoreUnnamedGroups);

if (mc.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (Match match in mc)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
    }
}
```

I was hoping match.Captures would contain only the captured groups by that is not the case.

Comment: FYI, the `Multiline` and `Singleline` options are not mutually exclusive, as you seem to think.  They're not even connected.  `Multiline` changes the behavior of the anchors (`^` and `$`) and `Singleline` changes the behavior of the dot (`.`).  The names are confusing and the matching modes they refer to never should have existed, but we're stuck with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
match.Groups[1].Value;
```

[Source](http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-match)

Comment: Works great, thanks. Can't load the link sadly (isp issues). Does the second group (group[1]) contains only the captures and the first one ([0]) the matches ?

Comment: In my understanding Groups contains only the groups... MatchCollection is what you are looking for. From msdn: *MatchCollection Represents the set of successful matches found by iteratively applying a regular expression pattern to the input string*